# How to count unique values in one colulmn based on value in another column by group in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to count unique values in one column only when the value meets a certain condition based on another column. For example, the data looks like this:

```
GroupID     ID       Value
ABC         TX123     0
ABC         TX678     1
ABC         TX678     2
DEF         AG123     1
DEF         AG123     1
DEF         AG123     1
GHI         TE203     0
GHI         TE203     0
```

I want to count the number of unique ID by Group ID but only when the value column >0. When all values for a group ID =0, it will simply have 0. For example, the result dataset would look like this:

```
GroupID    UniqueNum
ABC           1
DEF           1
GHI           0
```

I've tried the following but it simply returns the uique number of IDs regardless of its value. How do I add the condition of when value >0?

```
count_df = df.groupby(['GroupID'])['ID'].nunique()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### positive counts only

You can use pre-filtering with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and named aggregation with [`groupby.agg('nunique')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
(df.loc[df['Value'].gt(0), 'ID']
   .groupby(df['GroupID'])
   .agg(UniqueNum='nunique')
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
  GroupID  UniqueNum
0     ABC          1
1     DEF          1
```

##### all counts (including zero)

If you want to count as zero, the groups with no match, you can [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html):

```
(df.loc[df['Value'].gt(0), 'ID']
   .groupby(df['GroupID'])
   .agg(UniqueNum='nunique')
   .reindex(df['GroupID'].unique(), fill_value=0)
   .reset_index()
)
```

Or [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
(df['ID'].where(df['Value'].gt(0))
   .groupby(df['GroupID'])
   .agg(UniqueNum='nunique')
   .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
  GroupID  UniqueNum
0     ABC          1
1     DEF          1
2     GHI          0
```

Used input:

```
GroupID     ID       Value
ABC         TX123     0
ABC         TX678     1
ABC         TX678     2
DEF         AG123     1
DEF         AG123     1
DEF         AG123     1
GHI         AB123     0
```

Answer (score 0):

If need `0` for non matched values use [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) for `NaN`s for non matched condition, then aggregate by [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'GroupID': ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'DEF', 'DEF', 'NEW'],
                    'ID': ['TX123', 'TX678', 'TX678', 'AG123', 'AG123', 'AG123'],
                    'Value': [0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0]})

df = (df['ID'].where(df["Value"].gt(0)).groupby(df['GroupID'])
              .nunique()
              .reset_index(name='nunique'))

print (df)
  GroupID  nunique
0     ABC        1
1     DEF        1
2     NEW        0
```

How it working:

```
print (df.assign(new=df['ID'].where(df["Value"].gt(0))))
  GroupID     ID  Value    new
0     ABC  TX123      0    NaN
1     ABC  TX678      1  TX678
2     ABC  TX678      2  TX678
3     DEF  AG123      1  AG123
4     DEF  AG123      1  AG123
5     NEW  AG123      0    NaN <- set NaN for non matched condition
```